# How to get web midi output controller to work?

Tags: javascript, macos, midi, web-midi

So I have a midi controller connected to my machine, and I have it playing successfully with Logic Pro X on a mac.

I'm trying with Web Midi API to send a note to this midi controller, as an output device with the hope that it'll trigger the midi controller which will in turn trigger the sound via Logic.

I'm using [webmidi.js](https://github.com/djipco/webmidi) for this and I tried:

```
WebMidi.enable(function (err) {

  if (err) {
    console.log("WebMidi could not be enabled.", err);
  } else {
    console.log("WebMidi enabled!");
      console.log(WebMidi.inputs);
    console.log(WebMidi.outputs);
    var output = WebMidi.outputs[0];
    output.playNote("C3");
  }

});
```

yet I don't hear the note playing. I did make sure that my midi controller is listed as an output device.

The weird thing is when I playNote it actually lights up the LED key on the controller. But I still don't hear the sound. I also tried a different controller that doesn't have leds on the keys, but I also don't hear a sound.

I also tried going to this website http://webmidi-examples.glitch.me/ that on the last example also tries to send midi output but doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: I currently think sysex and https need to be enabled for this to work in chrome, I'm researching this.

Comment: ^ didn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this I found was to create a virtual midi device as output, and use this virtual midi device as input in my daw. Then use the code above but select the output as this new virtual midi device.

Steps on Mac: 
1. Audio Midi Setup -> Window -> Show Midi Studio.
2. In Midi Studio Double Click IAC Driver -> Create New Virtual Midi device with + Button on bottom left corner of screen. Check "Device is Online".

Go to DAW of your choice and change the input to this new midi device.
Now in javascript, using the code above, change to the new output:

```
var output = WebMidi.outputs[1]; // whatever index your virtual midi device is
```

Now it works.

From my experience I didn't need to enable sysex nor use https for this to work. I was just running the html on localhost on my node.js/express server.

Comment: Yeah, it's unlikely your controller is going to echo back its MIDI input without configuring it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an additional note, what the original question is asking isn't typical behaviour of a MIDI controller.  A MIDI controller will not echo MIDI IN data to its MIDI OUT.  However, some devices have MIDI THRU, which will send this traffic through.

This is important information because his code may work flawlessly, but appear to be broken because the MIDI hardware simply doesn't respond the way he's expecting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35608150)

Comment: Oh boy.  You must not understand MIDI if you think I wasn't answering the question.  He's asking how to receive MIDI input on a MIDI controller which would then be reflected on the MIDI OUT.  They simply don't work that way.  So the provided answer provides a workaround which involves adding an ADDITIONAL midi device (IAC - not in the orginal question, not a MIDI answer but a MAC answer) but doesn't answer the underlying question.  He's asking how to do something which, by design, the products typically don't do. This is why MIDI THRU exists!!!